# Practical reason for defining operator!=

Tags: c++, operators, comparison-operators

The following code will fail to compile under GCC because it *does* define `operator==` but does not define `operator!=`.

```
struct A {
    unsigned int m_i;
    bool operator == (const A& rhs) const { return m_i == rhs.m_i; }
};

bool f(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) { return lhs != rhs; }
```

Obviously it wants either

```
bool operator != (const A& rhs) const { return !(operator==(rhs)); }
```

or

```
bool operator != (const A& rhs) const { return m_i != rhs.m_i; }
```

Common wisdom seems to be that this is because `!operator==` adds an instruction and so is less efficient. This leads some programmers to dutifully write out their complex `!=` expression in full, and over the years I've fixed a number of bugs resulting from mismatched  operators.

Is this coercion to write both operators a case of premature/legacy optimization, or is there a good, solid, practical reason to do this code-doubling that I'm just somehow missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say absent some overwhelming evidence to the contrary, it's purely premature optimization (not even legacy--I doubt there was ever a good reason for it, at least in anything approaching a C++ time-frame).

For what it's worth, §20.2.1 of the C++ standard defines a number of overloads in `<utility>` that will give you a `!=` based on `operator==` and a `>`, `>=`, `<=` all based on `operator<`.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use this:

```
bool f(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }
```

Comment: Please read the question: specifically I wasn't asking how to fix it, and I already gave this as an example, you just omitted the `operator` of `operator==`.